# Get properties of file when Drag and drop file upload validation IE9, IE8 and IE7

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I have Implemented the drag and drop file upload using the plugin `Filedrop.js` on `asp.net` web application.I need the properties of the files before uploading it.

How can I get the properties of file once the file dropped into the browser before uploading the file? I need these properties from the `IE9`, `IE8` and `IE7` browsers.

```
<body>
<div id="zone" class="upload">
    <div id="dropIE9" class="drop" style="text-align: center; margin-bottom: 10px;">
        Drop or Upload         
        CSV File
        <br />
        <a>Browse</a>
        <br />
        <input id="fileCsvUploadIE9" type="file" style="opacity: 0; display: block;" />
    </div>
</div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     var options = { iframe: { url: 'FileUploadHandler.ashx'} };
     var zone = new FileDrop('zone', options);
     zone.event('send', function (files) {
         files.each(function (file) {             
             file.event('done', function (xhr) {
                 alert('Done uploading ' + this.name + ', response:\n\n' + xhr.responseText);
             });
             file.sendTo('FileUploadHandler.ashx');
         });
     });
     zone.event('iframeDone', function (xhr) {
         alert('Done uploading via <iframe>, response:\n\n' + xhr.responseText);
     });
     fd.addEvent(fd.byID('multiple'), 'change', function (e) {
         zone.multiple(e.currentTarget || e.srcElement.checked);
     });
</script>
```

Comment: Please show us your existing code. What properties of file do you want, and why?

Comment: I need the file name, file size and file type. So I can validate the file before uploading it

Comment: Doubt that you can do this at all in IE8 or IE7. The browser has to support what you are doing

Comment: I just checked, I could see the file is uploaded, when I dropped the file in to the browser IE9,IE8 and IE7. I need to validate before uploading it